# Using WRL in Windows runtime component to get folder path returns empty string

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, boost, windows-phone-8.1, wrl

I'm currently working on porting the Boost 'filesystem' library to Windows Phone 8.1.  I succeeded in porting about half of the problematic functions by substituting 'banned' Win32 API functions with other, newer non-banned functions.

I now need to tackle those Boost functions for which there is no alternative Win32 API.  Based on Steve Gates's excellent port of other Boost libraries to WP8.1, and in a private communication with him, I have decided to use WRL within the Boost code, rather than C++/CX.

To learn WRL and get my bearings, I wrote a minimal WP8.1 app consisting of a C++/CX client app that calls down into a Windows Runtime Component, the latter written in C++.  In the runtime component I have a function that attempts to determine the file system path of the Picture Library.  The problem I'm encountering is that the final path I get (i.e., pszPath) is an empty string.

Here is the runtime component code:

```
void Class1::Test1()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    HString hstrKnownFolders;
    hstrKnownFolders.Set(RuntimeClass_Windows_Storage_KnownFolders);

    // Get the Activation Factory
    ComPtr<IActivationFactory> pKnownFoldersActivationFactory;
    hr = ABI::Windows::Foundation::GetActivationFactory(hstrKnownFolders.Get(), 
                                                        &pKnownFoldersActivationFactory);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::Microsoft::WRL::Details::RaiseException(hr);
    }

    // QI for the IKnownFoldersStatics
    ComPtr<IKnownFoldersStatics> pKnownFolders;
    hr = pKnownFoldersActivationFactory.As(&pKnownFolders);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::Microsoft::WRL::Details::RaiseException(hr);
    }

    // Get the Pictures library folder
    ComPtr<IStorageFolder> pStorageFolder;
    hr = pKnownFolders->get_PicturesLibrary(&pStorageFolder);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::Microsoft::WRL::Details::RaiseException(hr);
    }

    // QI for the IStorageItem interface (from which IStorageFolder is derived)
    ComPtr<IStorageItem> pItem;
    hr = pStorageFolder.As(&pItem);

    // Get the path corresponding to the folder
    HSTRING hsPath;
    pItem->get_Path(&hsPath);
    PCWSTR pszPath = WindowsGetStringRawBuffer(hsPath, 0);
}
```

At the end of the function, the function get_Path() returns an empty string.  Can anyone shed light one what I'm doing wrong, and how it should be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No path is the right result: the Pictures library is a shell folder which compiles data from several locations (such as the public Pictures directory and the user's picture directory). The Pictures library itself doesn't have a path.

Individual items within the library probably have paths, but they may not be paths in the same file system directory.

StorageFiles are not limited to "files" from the file system. They can also include objects from elsewhere in the shell and objects from other apps. All of these are represented as file streams, but don't necessarily have file system paths.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out -- I remember reading this important issue somewhere in my learning journeys but it slipped my mind.  If I understand you correctly, if the StorageFolder object points to a folder or file beneath the Pictures library (virtual) folder, then get_Path() should return the actual physical location of the folder?  I will of course test this at work.  Many thanks for saving my sanity :-)